Why can Haskell lists be infinite in length whereas inductively defined sets must contain finite sized elements?
Sets that are defined inductively can only contain elements that finite in size (e.g., length, height, space). This can be intuitively proven by realizing that any element in such a set can be constructed by a finite number of applications of the induction rules.
In Haskell, we can define recursive lists like t = True : t, which is said to be an infinite list of True values. However, given the ADT for [a] (i.e., data [a] = a | a : [a]), we can construct the set of all values [Bool] can take (ignoring bottom value $\bot$).
$[Bool] = \{[]\} ∪ \{x:xs \mid x \in \{False, True\}, xs \in [Bool]\}$
This set also seems to be inductively/recursively defined, which means that any element of the set must be finite in length. This goes against our earlier assumption that t = True : t is infinite in length. Hence my question, how can we say that t is a list infinite in length when inductively defined sets can only contain finite sized elements?

What Haskell means by “infinite” is not necessarily what a set theorist means by “infinite.”

See here or here: the short answer is that Haskell has semantics in algebraically compact categories (which consist of objects like CPOs, rather than sets), which means that Haskell's data types are both inductive and coinductive.
The least fixed point of the $1 + A \times -$ endofunctor in CPOs, which interprets lists of $A$, has infinite elements.
